# Good way to combine a workstation and server?

Tags: debian, x-server

At work I have a Debian SSH server on which we perform computations (the points is that I can work on it also from home). But it is also my workstation when I'm at work.

At the moment I use the Caffeine app to keep it not falling asleep (otherwise I cannot connect to it at work).
But I'm afraid that this way I'm using too much resources when idle (which it is most of the time) - e.g. graphic card,...

What would be some nice options to make a compromise between a server and a workstation? Just quit x-server when I leave work? Since our firewall is quite strict I'm not sure I can use LAN wake-up.

Comment: please elaborate your question.